# Leaflet clustering choropleth regions

Tags: leaflet, choropleth

I'm fairly new to Leaflet library and I would like to ask if following functionality is somehow already implemented in Leaflet(or maybe in some other library).

I've found the following [example](http://bl.ocks.org/awoodruff/5de3553bb1f1b0c5f90d) which does clustering based on markers on the map and map also contains choropleth areas displayed.

My question is - Is it possible to do clustering based on choropleth data? Like if I have geojson data for some regions and would also have geojson data of subregions for every region. So if I do zooming then those subregions would collapse to big regions or big regions would be divided to small ones?

Big thanks for any advices or links!

Answer (score 1):

No, because clustering algorithms work only on point data.

You might want to just hide the regions and display the "subregions" when zooming in.

If data becomes too dense when zooming out, consider making the [union](http://turfjs.org/docs/#union) of the polygon geometries to display that instead. A naïve algorithm would be search for the smallest polygon, then search for the smallest neighboring polygon, replace them by their union, repeat. Stop the algorithm when the smallest polygon is larger than a given threshold.